# Kotlin Ktor Exception in thread "main" NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: kotlin, gradle, jar, ktor

I'm new to ktor.

I developed simple app and I want to run it

here is my `main` function

```
fun main() {
embeddedServer(
    factory = CIO,
    port = 8080,
    host = "0.0.0.0",
    module = {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json()
        }
        configureDependencyInjection()

        configureCategoryRouting()
        configureImageRouting()

        Database.connect(
            url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres",
            driver = "org.postgresql.Driver",
            user = "xxxxxxxx",
            password = "xxxxxxxxxx"
        )
        transaction {
            SchemaUtils.create(Categories, Images)
        }

    }
).start(
    wait = true
)
}
```

I did Build a Jar file with this command in linux
`./gradlew installDist`

here is my `build.gradle.kts`

```
val ktorVersion: String by project
val kotlinVersion: String by project
val logbackVersion: String by project
val exposedVersion: String by project
val koinVersion: String by project

plugins {
application
kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.20"
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.6.20"
id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.0.0"
} 

group = "wallpaper.io"
version = "0.0.1"
application {
mainClass.set("wallpaper.io.ApplicationKt")

val isDevelopment: Boolean = project.ext.has("development")
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf("-Dio.ktor.development=$isDevelopment")
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url = uri("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/ktor/eap") }
}

tasks.withType<Jar> {
manifest {
    attributes["Main-class"] = "wallpaper.io.ApplicationKt"
}
}


dependencies {
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core-jvm:$ktorVersion")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-content-negotiation-jvm:$ktorVersion")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json-jvm:$ktorVersion")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-html-builder-jvm:$ktorVersion")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty-jvm:$ktorVersion")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-cio-jvm:$ktorVersion")
implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logbackVersion")

implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktorVersion")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktorVersion")

implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-ktor:$koinVersion")
implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-logger-slf4j:$koinVersion")

implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktorVersion")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktorVersion")

implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-core:$exposedVersion")
implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-dao:$exposedVersion")
implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-jdbc:$exposedVersion")
implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.3")

implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-java-time:$exposedVersion")
}
```

when i use this command `java -jar Wallpaper-Backend-0.0.1.jar` i get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/ktor/server/cio/CIO
at wallpaper.io.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:19)
at wallpaper.io.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt)
```

any idea what is my problem?

Comment: Never used Kotlin. This link might help you out: https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-documentation/tree/main/codeSnippets/snippets/embedded-server

Comment: Could you please try using the ShadowJar Gradle plugin https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction/ that bundles all dependencies in a single JAR file?